# Understanding the Poisson Memorylessness Proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poissons-equation

I was hoping someone can explain to me step by step the proof of Poisson memorylessness property. First i understand that ,

```
1. Memoryless: P(X>s + t|X>t) = P(X>s).
```

From that point the rule of conditional probability is used which will then simplify to :

```
2.P(X>s + t, X > t)/P(X>t)
```

But from this point, i don't understand the mathematics involved in these subsequent phases. Please explain as you would to a novice how each step is simplified, my background in mathematics is average.

```
3.P(X>s + t)/P(X>t)
4.e−λ(s+t)/e−λt
5.e−λs
6.P(X>s)
```

Comment: Step 3. If $X>t$ **and** it is also true that $X > s+t$, then, for $s > 0$, is it not correct that the first statement is redundant; since $X > s+t$, we already know that $X > t$ without needing to be told this separately.

Answer (score 2):

*3.* $[X\gt s+t,X\gt t]=[X\gt s+t]$ since $s\geqslant0$.

*4.* Definition of exponential CDF is $P(X\gt x)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}$ for every $x\geqslant0$.

*5.* Obvious.

*6.* Definition of exponential CDF.

Comment: Thanks i now understand. The CDF was the missing piece. Please if this doesn't irritate you, i don't get the most simple obvious step 5. Sorry :(

Comment: ?? What do you know about the exponential function?

Comment: i feel stupid right now. I now know why :D If we are dividing  exponents of the same base we can just subtract the powers